# Was the Jewish population expelled from the Jerusalem after the siege of 70 AD or after the Bar Kokhba revolt?

Tags: roman-empire, christianity, jerusalem, judaism

The Wikipedia article on Bar Kokhba revolt [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Kokhba_revolt#Aftermath) :

> and Jews were forbidden from entering it, except on the day of Tisha
>   B'Av.

I was under the impression that the Jewish population had already been expelled after the siege of 70 AD. Or was it, that they were heavily persecuted, but not expelled in 70AD ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographic_history_of_Palestine_(region) Jewish majority in the 4th century, the remainder Christians (presumably converted Jews).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Jewish population was not expelled in 70. At least Josephus, our the main source 
on that war does not say this. Jerusalem was destroyed, and the Temple was robbed,
burned and closed (closed few years after the siege). He also mentions that lands
belonging to the Jews were confiscated. But he does not say that population was expelled.

Answer (score 1):

According to Josephus's account Jerusalem was razed to the ground & most of  those who didn't perish from starvation in the seige  were killed defending the Temple.

From what Josephus writes it seems like there was:

1. No Jerusalem. It suffered a similar fate to Carthage by being utterly destroyed.
2. There weren't many Jews left to expel. We know many were taken as slaves back to Rome & also this conquest of Judaea funded the building of the Flavian ampitheatre, the Colosseum.

Comment: Could you give us a link as to where you read this?

Comment: No because i didnt read it online but u can type in any search engine" the siege of Jerusalem"by Josephus I'm sure you'll get numerous hits